# Rewrite the list without certain elements in the sequence

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, filtering, sequence

I have a `list1`:

```
list1={{" r1 =", 0.`, " r2 =", 0.`, " t =", 0.043, " RK =", 0.94}, {" r1 =",
   0.`, " r2 =", 0.`, " t =", 0.130, " RK =", 2.5}, {" r1 =", 0.`, 
  " r2 =", 0.`, " t =", 0.218, " RK =", 5.29}, {" r1 =", 5.`, " r2 =",
   5.`, " t =", 6.152, " RK =", 1.498}, {" r1 =", 5.`, " r2 =", 5.`, 
  " t =", 6.239, " RK =", 4.094}}
```

I need to get `list2` from `list1`.

```
list2={{{0.`, 0.`, 0.043}, 
  0.94}, {{0.`, 0.`, 0.130}, 2.5}, {{0.`, 0.`, 0.218}, 
  5.29}, {{5.`, 5.`, 6.152}, 1.498}, {{5.`, 5.`, 6.239}, 4.094}}
```

To get `list2`, I have removed strings and added extra curly braces around every first three elements. Is it possible to do this without a lot of loops? Could you show it?

In my original lists, there are a few thousand elements.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way:

```
FlattenAt[TakeDrop[#, 3], -1] & /@ DeleteCases[list1, _String, Infinity]
```

Explanation:

We start by deleting the strings

```
DeleteCases[list1, _String, Infinity]
```

Adding the extra layer of list structure to the first three element is a bit trickier, and maybe someone else will have something more elegant to suggest. `TakeDrop` gets you close. For example:

```
TakeDrop[{0.`, 0.`, 0.043`, 0.94`}, 3]
(* {{0., 0., 0.043}, {0.94}} *)
```

We don't like that extra list at the last position. One way to get rid of it is to `FlattenAt`:

```
FlattenAt[TakeDrop[{0.`, 0.`, 0.043`, 0.94`}, 3], -1]
(* {{0., 0., 0.043}, 0.94} *)
```

Okay, now turn that into a function that we can map over our "clean" data, and you have what I posted first above.

Answer (score 2):

```
res1 = {Most@#, Last@#} & /@ DeleteCases[list1, _?(StringQ), {2}]
```

OR

```
res2 = SequenceReplace[
  list1, {{a_String, b_?NumericQ, c_String, d_?NumericQ, e_String, 
     f_?NumericQ, g_String, h_?NumericQ}} :> {{b, d, f}, h}
  ]
```

OR

```
res3 = {#[[1 ;; 3]], #[[-1]]} &@#[[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]] & /@ list1
```

OR

```
res4 = First@SequenceReplace[#, {a_, b_, c_, d_} :> {{a, b, c}, d}] & /@
  (SequenceReplace[#, {a_String, b_?NumericQ} :> b] & /@ list1)
```

---

Output:

```
> {{{0., 0., 0.043}, 0.94}, {{0., 0., 0.13}, 2.5}, {{0., 0., 0.218}, 
>   5.29}, {{5., 5., 6.152}, 1.498}, {{5., 5., 6.239}, 4.094}}
```

---

Check:

```
res1 == res2 == res3 == res4 == list2
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

```
res = list1 /. {_, r1_, _, r2_, _, t_, _, rk_} :> {{r1, r2, t}, rk}
res == list2
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `GatherBy`:

```
{Most@#, Last@#} & @@@ Outer[List, Last@GatherBy[#, Head] & /@ list1, 1] === list2

(*True*)
```